# How to make a double relatiobnship using a Spring Boot project +JPA?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Have a project with 4 tables: `users`, `companies`, `roles` and `user_roles_relationships`.

In the `user_roles_relationships` have 3 columns: `user_id`, `role_id` and `company_id`.

Each user have a different role for each company.

I use JPA but, how to get all companies from specific user?, for example, in the list companies section need show all companies associated to the current authenticated user.

In SQL is easy, make a inner join using the relationships table and company table and a where clausle, but how to works in the repository?

The ideal query is:

```
SELECT companies.*
FROM companies
INNER JOIN user_groups_relatinships ON (user_groups_relatinships.company_id = companies.id)
INNER JOIN users ON (users.id = user_groups_relatinships.user_id)
WHERE users.id = ?
```

I have a tree entities, the user, the company and the role, the user entity have a role relationship using the `@ManyToMany` annotation, and the company no have relationships annotations.

Comment: Your description of your entities doesn't match with the description of your tables. If user and role have a ManyToMany relationship, then you have a join table with just two columns, not three. So your mapping is incorrect. You need an entity that maps the user_roles_relationships table. It would have 3 ManyToOne annotations.

Comment: @JBNizet the 3rd column is used in loggin process and the sections access, but not for see list own companies.